# Add track to playlist SoundCloud API

Tags: windows-phone-8, soundcloud

In my Windows Phone App, I'm using the following code to add a track to playlist (i.e. a PUT request to playlists/id endpoint)

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(data));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
```

where "data" is JSON data the form:

> {"playlist":{"tracks":["TrackId(to be added)"]}}

The above code returns "OK"(200) response but the track is NOT added to the playlist!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the JSON data (of the request body) was not formatted correctly.
"data" must be of the form:

```
    {"playlist":{"tracks":[{"id":"__"}, {"id":"__"}, {"id":"__"}]}}
```

Here the id-value pair must be present for

- every track already present in the playlist, as well as
- the track that you want to add to the playlist

(Remember, this is a PUT request. So, you need to update data i.e. update the "tracks" property of the "playlist")

Answer (score 1):

I use Put to replace track ids in set.
here is sample code

```
for (String s : trackIds)
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("playlist[tracks][][id]", s.trim()));

String url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/" + setId + ".json";
httpPut(url, nameValuePairs);
```

Comment: Do i need to send all other trackIds (of the tracks already present in the playlist) in addition to the trackId(of the track to be added), in the request body in the form: { playlist : { tracks : [] } } for this PUT request. After trying this approach, I'm getting 422(Unprocessable entity). Also, in your answer: "s" is the trackId (if I got it right ), but what is the name in the nameValuePair, if you could elaborate? :)

Comment: i think i had similar problems, and that's why i ended with replacing all trackIds.