# When PUTting to a playlist on Soundcloud's API, the playlist doesn't actually get updated?

Tags: soundcloud

When I try to HTTP PUT a SoundCloud playlist through the API, with a data structure: `{"tracks": [{"id": 12345}, {"id": 45678}]}`, the playlist doesn't get updated. The API returns a 200 response with what was in the playlist, completely ignoring the modifications.

## What I think might be wrong

1. The SoundCloud API doesn't accept that format of data
2. Somehow the authorization is invalid, even though it's returning a 200

### The code:

```
import requests
playlist_url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/XXXXX?client_id=XXXXX'
like_url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/users/XXXXX/favorites?client_id=XXXXX'
likes = requests.get(like_url)
likes_json = likes.json()

# oauth2_token = requests.post('https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token', data=opts).json()
oauth2_token = 'XXXXX'
playlist = {'tracks': []}
for like in likes_json[::-1]:
    track_id = like['id']
    playlist['tracks'].append({'id': track_id})

resp = requests.put('https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/XXXXX', json=playlist, params={
                                                                                'oauth_token': oauth2_token,
                                                                                'client_id': 'XXXXX',
                                                                                'client_secret': 'XXXXX'
                                                                                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was simply sending the wrong data structure. It should have been `{'playlist': {'tracks': [{'id': 1234}, {'id': 4567}]}}`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28847716/2350164